# Need to loop through range of values in replace function using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a macro that references a two columns of values on one sheet, and uses those values to replace the values in a column on another sheet.

For example:

In Sheet2, the value of range("A2") is *LosAngeles* and the value of range("B2") is California. Then, the value of range("A3") is *Manhattan* and the value of range("B3") is New York, and the lists go on. These lists are also dynamic and will be changed every day.

On Sheets("Name"), I have a list of strings that need to be searched for the values in column A on sheet2 (the cities), and replaced with the values in Column B on sheet2 (the states).

This is what I have so far, but unfortunately I am getting an error saying:

> Run-time error: '5'" Invalid procedure call or arguement

when I get to:

```
Selection.Replace What:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells("i,1").Value, Replacement:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("i,2").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Below is the entire subroutine. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance so much!

```
Sub MatchHelp()

Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Name As Worksheet
Dim OriginalText As Variant

Set Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name")

lastRow = Name.Range("A" & Name.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To lastRow
    Name.Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells("i,1").Value, Replacement:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("i,2").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Cells("i,1")` is incorrect.  `Cells()` format is `Cells(Row,Column)` so in your case `.Cells(i,1)` or `.Cells(i,"A")`

Comment: and same applies to `.Range("i,2").Value`

Comment: The range as @dbmitch stated needs to be `.Range("B" & i)`  variables need to concatenated outside the quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! It runs perfectly now.